# SP Designer modified content deployment to the production server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, content-deployment

I have a question here on deployment to production server. Definitely this is not related to content deployment path/job to the production server. In our development set up we will create all web applications, site collections etc. through PowerShell scripts. We will maintain all scripts in a document and same scripts can be run in production server. Now If we add any OOB content to various sites (e.g. XSLT list view web part & customize that) through the SP Designer, how can we take those SP designer content to the production server? I mean how can we resemble same customized XSLT web part to the production server in the same site?

We don't want to take any test data, that is why content DB is not taken, but we want to take all OOB web parts etc created for site collection in the production server? I know how workflow, SSRS, info path etc is taken. They have separate ways. But how to take development with SharePoint designer?

For custom development I understand that all will be taken as WSP file, but my question is how content added in SP designer will be taken to the server?

Can you please guide what is the actual steps/ process of taking all content to the production server from Development server?

Can any experts reply with real life answer for my specific question on deployment of SharePoint Designer content to production server?

Comment: can we use http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/ for this purpose?